# How should I arrange files for good performance (with a PHP program that run across multiple machines)

Tags: php, cloud

This is my first time to run a PHP script on multiple machine, so please forgive my ignorance

Below is the case: I'm setting up 3 different servers:

1. the core server which should hold all the Symfony vendor code
2. the files server for storing assets like images, static files etc.The storage is mounted (nfs) to core server.
3. the database server

Now I wonder where should I put my public_html folder. It seems like I have 2 choices:

1. Put the public_html folder on the core machine, put static files to files server and symlink them to the public_html folder (they are on the same local network)
2. Put the public_html folder on the files server

Also, say if I put public_html/index.php on the files server which has its storage mounted to the core server, then the load (cpu, ram) will incur on which server?

Comment: Probably a question more suited to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i see, should i close this one and post there, is there a move function?